# How to handle different JSONs that have the same structure but different properties inside?

Tags: java, json, rest, generics, model

I have to handle REST calls to a suite of web services. All of those REST web services return a JSON that will have the following structure

```
{
   "header":{
      "code":"",
      "value":""
   },
   "payload":{
      "objectWithDifferentKey":{
         //this object will have different structure and key depending on which web service is called by the client
      }
   }
}
```

How can I model this structure without replicating each time the header+payload structure for each object, but using something like Generics / @JsonInfo or similar?

I started with the following approach but I cannot figure out how to model the Payload object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class ResponseObject {

    @JsonProperty("header")
    private Header header;
        
    @JsonProperty("payload")
    private Payload payload;

}
    
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Header {
        
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;
        
}
    
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class Payload {
    //don't know what to put inside and how to handle the different keys
    //into the payload I always have only one object with key based on the web service I'm calling
}
    
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class ObjectWithDifferentKey1 {
        
    //properties inside
        
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class ObjectWithDifferentKey2 {
    //properties inside
}
```

Can someone give me an idea about that?

Comment: I would think (comming mainly from c#) that you could use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of the `ObjectWithDifferentKeyN` classes or make `Payload` a generic type and use it like `Payload<ObjectWithDifferentKeyN>`

Comment: I thought about that, but then I don't know what to put in the JsonProperty annotation. Because when the JSON object is returned, the parser searches for a specific key in JsonProperty (or, alternatively, an attribute that matches the key in the json.

Answer (score 0):

Your case calls for handling dynamic deserialization. One way to achieve this is by using a `Map` object. Another is using the `JsonNode` object offered by `Jackson` as a placeholder for your `payload` object. An example could be the following:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Header {

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;

}
```

And

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResponseObject {

    private static final String EXAMPLE_1 = "{\n"
    + "\t\"header\": {\n"
    + "\t\t\"code\": \"\",\n"
    + "\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n"
    + "\t},\n"
    + "\t\"payload\": {\n"
    + "\t\t\"something\": \"value\",\n"
    + "\t\t\"something2\": \"value2\"\n"
    + "\t}\n"
    + "}";

    private static final String EXAMPLE_2 = "{\n"
    + "\t\"header\": {\n"
    + "\t\t\"code\": \"\",\n"
    + "\t\t\"value\": \"\"\n"
    + "\t},\n"
    + "\t\"payload\": {\n"
    + "\t\t\"blah\": \"value\",\n"
    + "\t\t\"blah2\": \"value2\"\n"
    + "\t}\n"
    + "}";

    @JsonProperty("header")
    private Header header;

    @JsonProperty("payload")
    private JsonNode payload;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        var response1 =  mapper.readValue(EXAMPLE_1, ResponseObject.class);
        var response2 = mapper.readValue(EXAMPLE_2, ResponseObject.class);
        var writer = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        Stream.of(response1, response2).forEach(responseObject -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(responseObject));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        });
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

And the output would be something like this:

```json
{
  "header" : {
    "code" : "",
    "value" : ""
  },
  "payload" : {
    "something" : "value",
    "something2" : "value2"
  }
}
{
  "header" : {
    "code" : "",
    "value" : ""
  },
  "payload" : {
    "blah" : "value",
    "blah2" : "value2"
  }
}
```

That way you want have to worry about the content and the structure of the `payload` field. Note that this is only one way of achieving this. As of the `jsonProperty` annotation, this is used only for naming convention on the produced JSON.